# Error: Using if within a while loop

Tags: bash

I have written a script that reads multiple lines of files-names from which the script picks up the file one by one and if the file-name ends with Java then a `pmd` check is performed on the code. That was the idea with which it was written. But an error is thrown when the script below is executed and the line it points to is `then` which is part of the `if` construct used within `while`.

The `$git diff origin/master..master --name-only` returns `HelloWorld.java`. And yes, I know that I may have to pass the locations to search and append that to `$each_file` in the script.

But mainly I want the solution as to why this script returns an error as shown below. Is the error resulting because of the pattern matching code i.e the `if` block?

The script as a whole is supposed to run a `pmd` check on every changed file in the repository. If that helps at all for you to answer my question.

The script is displayed below:

```
#\bin\bash
changed_files=$(git diff origin/master..master --name-only)
export PATH=$PATH:pmd/bin
while read each_file
do
        if[$each_file == *.java]
        then
                exec $(run.sh pmd -d $each_file  -f text -R rulesets/internal/all-java.xml)
        fi
done<$changed_files
```

Output:

```
Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "done")
```

Comment: you missed a white space after the `if`

Comment: ...and after `[` and before `]`. And your shebang is broken. And are you sure you want to use `exec` *and* `$()`?

Comment: try `help [`  ... it is a command, not a syntax element in bash

Comment: @dennis Oh, and that's not regex. And the parameters to `[` don't look  quite right (see `man [`), maybe you should use `[[` instead. I recommend `man bash` and http://www.shellcheck.net .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `[` and `]` characters are not parsed by bash like you expect; `[` is an actual command, and all commands need to be separated by whitespace (and the closing `]` is a parameter to `[`, so it also needs to be separated by whitespace). Therefore, you need to place whitespace *before* and *after* the brackets.

I also added quotes around the env variable for good measure.

Also, you seem to want to run the pmd source code analyzer. It's output will be a textual (or html, etc) report. You can't `exec` text data, so I removed that exec as well.

```
#\bin\bash
changed_files=$(git diff origin/master..master --name-only)
export PATH=$PATH:pmd/bin
while read each_file
do
        if [ "$each_file" == "*.java" ]
        then
                run.sh pmd -d $each_file  -f text -R rulesets/internal/all-java.xml
        fi
done<$changed_files
```

There's still more problems to work out with what's currently there, but this should answer your question.

---

```
#/bin/bash
changed_files=$(git diff origin/master..master --name-only)
export PATH=$PATH:pmd/bin
while read each_file
do
    run.sh pmd -d $each_file  -f text -R rulesets/internal/all-java.xml
done<$changed_files
```

I modified it again. `each_file` only comes as a result of a git diff command, which will *never* be '*.java'. So I had it run the `run.sh` on every item without the if altogether.

Also, the `\bin\bash` was changed to `/bin/bash`.

Is the `run.sh` a script you made? or is that in the pmd/bin folder? I'm guessing you don't need to put run.sh in there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: ok. Thank you for the correction. What is it then? (so that I can update my answer)

Comment: It's just an argument to `[` that marks the end of the test. If you run `[` without it it will complain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested in hearing about the other problems that exist in the script. Please do share the information as well. Thank you once again.